# Variable on both Sides, Exponential = Binomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you solve the following exponential equation:

$2^x = -2x+11$

I already tried graphing and "guessing and checking," but I would like to know if it's possible to solve this algebraically.

The answer is approximately $ 2.6 $

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your best bet is a numerical method.

Comment: In general, this kind of problem can't be solved in terms of elementary functions. But you might check out the Lambert-$W$ function.

Comment: Was this a homework problem given in a class, or did you come up with it on your own? If its the first, what class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ar looking for the zero(s) of function
$$f(x)=2^x+2x-11=e^{x \log(2)}+2x-11$$

As said in comments, the solution is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$x=\frac{11}{2}-\frac{W\left(16 \sqrt{2} \log (2)\right)}{\log (2)}\approx 2.55719 $$
The linked page clearly explains the steps and also shows how to evaluate $W(.)$ using series.

Notice that 
$f'(x)=2^x \log (2)+2$ never cancels in the real domain making the root to be unique.

I you do not want (or cannot use) this function, the simplest would be Newton method. Plottiing the function, you notice that the solution is close to $2$. Then, use $x_0=2$ and the iterates would be given by
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ So, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.000000000 \\
 1 & 2.628589676 \\
 2 & 2.558377938 \\
 3 & 2.557193278 \\
 4 & 2.557192952
\end{array}
\right)$$